# Geometric intuition for adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Then $T^*$ ($T$ adjoint) is defined as the unique function such that $\langle T(x), y \rangle = \langle x, T^*(y) \rangle$ for all $x, y \in V$. Furthermore, $T^*$ is linear.

I know how to manipulate the adjoint algebraically, but I'm not sure how to interpret it geometrically.

This has been asked before, but the previous questions did not suit my needs.

[Definition of adjoint operator (asking for intuition)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3578769) I'm not asking about $T^*$'s relation to $A$'s conjugate transpose.

[Geometric intuition of adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/472761) I'm asking about intuition about $T^*$, not $\text{Ker}(T^*)=(\text{Im}(T))^\perp$.

https://mathoverflow.net/q/6552 The answers to this question feel too complicated to me.

- https://mathoverflow.net/q/6573 I haven't yet learned about Hilbert spaces. Also, I don't know what $\langle \: |$ and $| \: \rangle$ are.
- https://mathoverflow.net/q/6567 biadjacency matrix?

Comment: In a finite-dimensional inner product space, Riesz representation theorem simply means that every linear functional $f\in V^\ast$ can be expressed as an inner product with a fixed vector. That is, there is some $v\in V$ such that $f(x)$ is identically equal to $\langle v,x\rangle$. One of the linked answers in your question uses this fact to explain why the adjoint of a rank-one linear operator exists. Since a rank-$r$ linear operator is just a sum of $r$ rank-one linear operators, it follows that the adjoint of a linear operator always exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a geometric intuition. Nevertheless I find it pretty enlightning, so I hope to be helpful.

Given a linear operator $T:V\to V$, you can define the transpose operator:

$$T^t:V^*\to V^*$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \varphi \mapsto \varphi\circ T$$

The transpose operator is essentially the simplest way you can imagine to construct an operator on $V^*$ using an operator $T$ on $V$.
If you understand this then the adjoint is straight forward!
In fact the idea is to use the fact that $V$ is isomorphic to its dual $V^*$. Normally there aren't natural isomorphism between a space and its dual, but in this case you are in a inner product (finite dimensional ) space!
So you can construct a canonical isomorphism(actually if the field is $\mathbb{C}$, this is conjugate-linear):

$$\omega:V\to V^*$$
$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   v \mapsto \langle \bullet,v\rangle=\omega_v$$

(Basically you associate to a vector $v$ the linear functional $w\mapsto \langle w,v \rangle$).

Now the adjoint is simply the transpose "re-interpreted" through this natural isomorphism:

$$T^*=\omega^{-1}\circ T^t \circ \omega:V\to V$$

As you can see the adjoint is simply a natural reinterpretation of the transpose, so if you find the transpose intuitive, you should also find the adjoint intuitive.

Clearly I should prove that my definition of $T^*$ coincides with yours, and this is straightforward:

$$\langle T(x),y \rangle=\langle x,T^*(y) \rangle \ \text{for all } x,y \iff  $$

$$\iff  \omega_y(T(x))=\omega_{T^*(y)}(x) \ \text{for all } x,y \iff $$

$$\iff  \omega_y\circ T=\omega_{T^*(y)} \ \text{for all } y \iff $$

$$\iff  T^t(\omega_y)=\omega_{T^*(y)} \ \text{for all } y \iff $$

$$\iff  (T^t\circ \omega)(y)=(\omega \circ T^*)(y) \ \text{for all } y   \iff $$

$$\iff  T^t\circ \omega=\omega \circ T^*   \iff $$

$$\iff T^*=\omega^{-1}\circ T^t \circ \omega  $$

Comment: Very good answer! (Assuming the OP knows what $V^*$ and its elements are.) But I think you don't need the fact that $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic. The first 6 lines (up until 'straight forward!') would entail an entirely fine answer by itself in my opinion, even (or especially) in a hypothetical (or infinite dimensional) world where $V*$ is not isomorphic to $V$.

Comment: Hi @Vincent , thank you for your kindness. Truly, I studied this topic only in the realm of finite dimensional spaces, so I don't really know deeply how infinite-dimensional spaces work. For sure in this broader setting, $\omega$ may not be an isomorphism, so this construction fails. I don't think that reducing the answer to the first 6 lines is a good idea, since the OP refers to the adjoint as an operator on $V$ and not on its dual(the question isn't about the transpose).

Comment: @Eureka $\omega$ is an isomorphism if $V$ is a Hilbert space, though if $V$ is a complex vector space, $\omega$ will be conjugate linear rather than linear. This is the content of the Riesz representation theorem for Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Right, good point.

Comment: @Mason Thank you for this insight, infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces seem really wonderful structures. It's a pity I didn't studied them yet.

Comment: Stupid question: why do we care at all about dual spaces?

Comment: @NoppaweeApichonpongpan Linear functional are everywhere in mathematics: derivatives, integrals, differentials, singular cochains, ...